# Constants/Variable AND Non-Mutable/Mutable

Tags: objective-c, swift

Today one of my student asked me what is the technical difference between these two concepts

1. Constant and Variable
2. Non Mutable and Mutable

because we know Constants are Non Mutable and Variables are Mutable. 
I told him that Mutable/Non Mutable is concept of Cocoa Framework and Constants/Variable is not. But i am not sure i was right

I know its usage but didn't find any proper technical answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are right about constants being non-mutable and variables being mutable.

The mutable vs non-mutable in the cocoa framework are often ties to data structures (such as arrays, queues, dictionaries, etc).

Where mutable means we can alter the data structure (add/remove objects) and immutable means we can't modify it (just read).

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Constness in Objective-C referes to object references, but never to objects (as i. e. in C++). Mutability refers to objects.

```
// non-const reference to immutable string object
NSString *s = …; 
// You can change the reference, …
s = …; // No error
// … but not the string object
[s appendString:…]; // Error

// const reference to immutable string object
const NSString* s = …;
// You can neither change the reference, …
s = …; // Error
// … nor the string object
[s appendString:…]; // Error

// non-const reference to mutable string object
NSMutableString *s = …;
// You can change the reference …
s = …; // No Error
// … and the string object
[s appendString:…]; // No error

// const reference to mutable string object
const NSMutableString *s = …;
// You cannot change the reference, …
s = …; // Error
// … but the string object
[s appendString:…];
```

So you can say that immutability is the "constness of (OOP) objects".

However constness of "variables" (to be more precise: C objects that are no Objective-C objects) is important to the compiler for optimization, because it is SSA. Immutability is important for many things in your design.

Even for (Objective-C) objects immutability is important and not as often considered as it should be. Especcially for "data classes" that are passed around, an immutable version should be considered making things easier. This applies to your own classes, too.